# Shim or map javax.ws.rs to jakarta.ws.rs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm looking for a shim or proxy to forward calls from javax.ws.rs to jakarta.ws.rs namespace. I have external dependencies which consume javax.ws.rs. In general I'm looking for something what exists in the javascript eco system, like core.js.

RESTeasy 6 recently implement Jakarta RESTful Web Services and drop the support for javax.ws.rs package namespace. Now i'm looking for something like a brigde/proxy/shim which redirect calls from javax.ws.rs to jakarta.ws.rs.

I would like to avoid something like reflection or bytecode manipulation if possible.

I'm using maven to build my project. Existing code related to this question can be found here: https://github.com/adorsys/keycloak-config-cli/pull/615

Wait until all dependencies are updated to Jakarta RESTful Web Services would the best solution. But it unknown to me if it happends in the near future.

TL;DR: I'm looking for something what is known from the logging subsystems, like log4j-slf4j-impl or jul-to-slf4j. javaee-jakataee-impl or javaee-to-jakataee

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you aren’t looking at an implementation .jar file’s packages?  javax.ws.rs [is still the official base package of JAX-RS](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html), same as it’s always been.

Comment: Now sure what you're looking for. All those API classes don't actually do _antything_. They are basically interfaces we can program against. But there is no engine in the API (specification) classes. The engine comes with the _implementation_

Comment: There is a migration tool that can migrate all your javax classes to Jakarta without having to manually do it yourself.

Comment: I'm looking for something like javaee-jakataee-impl, like log4j-slf4j-impl

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this will not be possible. Probably you'll need to wait for your dependencies also use the Jakarta namespace

Comment: FWIW RESTEasy 5.0 is still Jakarta REST 2.1 so you could use that version instead.

Comment: Having some sort of javaee to jakarta ee proxy class will make the migration so much easier - I'm surprised it hasn't been done already. Google's various Java SDKs rely on lots of javax classes and they need to support Java 7 (due to Android support), so they won't upgrade their libraries to Jakarta anytime soon.